# Android stay app active

Tags: android

I would like to stay my android application active when it working, and I am using FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag for this purpose, but I don't want always keep screen on, because it's not economic for battery. I want to use a standard behavior - when user touch screen - he's lighting up, and after some time of inactive turn off. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking at `PowerManager.WakeLock`, in particular the `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` flag, this will keep the CPU running yet let the screen turn off. If you take this approach, make sure you **release** the `WakeLock` when you are done with it.

You can find out more about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: I tried to use this flag. In this case android stopped my application after screen is locked and fire onPause() method.

Comment: Yes, when the screen is locked onPause() will be called. You can't really do anything about it unless you can settle with the SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK. You should write your application to handle the onPause() as a lot of things can trigger this (e.g. phone call).